# different behavior of "ls()" depending on cache=T or cache=F in a knitr Rmd document

Tags: r, knitr

The following simple test.Rmd knitr document

````
```{r}
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
```

```{r}
x <- 1
```

```{r}
x
ls()
```
````

when processed from the Unix shell with:

```
R -e 'library(knitr) ; knit("test.Rmd")'
pandoc -s -f markdown -t latex test.md -o test.tex
pdflatex test.tex
```

produces a pdf file (test.pdf) with the following output:

```
x <- 1

x

## [1] 1

ls()

## character(0)
```

that is, the output of the last code chunk shows first the contents of `x` while the `ls()` call does not show that there is an object called `x` in the workspace. If I disable the `cache` by removing the first code chunk, then `ls()` shows `x` as I had expected. I could not figure out from the documentation the reason for this behavior of `ls()` when `opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)` is used. Can somebody explain to me why this happens and how could I have `ls()` behaving in the same way with and without caching?

thanks!!

robert.
ps: here is my `sessionInfo()` when appended to the `knit()` call:

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                LC_NAME=C                
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3   evaluate_0.4.3 formatR_0.7    stringr_0.6.2  tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: Just FYI: this problem has been fixed in the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme).

Answer (score 0):

Update: this problem has been fixed in the [knitr development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme). The answer below can be ignored.

---

You can consider this as a bug. I have been thinking for a long time on this issue since it has been reported for a few times. I will address it in the next version (1.2).

As for the reason, it is because `knitr` uses a separate empty environment to evaluate the code when `cache = TRUE`, and the parent frame of this environment is the global environment by default, so `x` is accessible but does not really exist in this empty environment. Hopefully the code below explains it better:

```
x = 1
env = new.env(parent = parent.frame())
ls(env)  # character(0), nothing there
exists('x', envir = env, inherits = FALSE) # FALSE
env$x  # NULL
get('x', envir = env)  # 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the code. I was afraid I was not understanding how `knitr` was working. I look forward to the newer version.

Comment: @robertc The new version is on CRAN now.